# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ctrl+shift to change language

Tags: shortcuts, input-language

Do you have some idea? In this version there's no Advanced Settings button in the Keybord section in Settings so I don´t know how to make a shortcut to change language.

Answer (score 0):

You can find (and change) the key combinations in: Settings - Keyboard - Keyboard shortcuts - Type.
My language is Dutch, it may be slightly different than what I am stating here but you should be able to find them.

Comment: Yes, I know this place. But I could´t find this shorcut. I've searched for the third time and I've understood why  I couldn't find it. Cause the name is like "Switches to the next input source", I've just haven't expected it could be this. Thank you for motivating me :)

Comment: @Jaszczurka: Well, you can't set the Ctrl+Shift shortcut there anyway. To set that shortcut, install `gnome-tweaks` and do it from Tweaks. OTOH, if you are on Wayland there is a related bug: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916

Comment: Thanks, I think I can stand SUPER + SPACE :)